# If Radio button is checked method android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, radio-button, ischecked

Hey i have this code in java:

```
If (Yes.isChecked()){
                FreeEvent = "True";
            } else{
                FreeEvent = "False"; }
```

Yes is a radio button and FreeEvent is a string and both are setup fine.
I want to execute Line2 if the radio button Yes is checked, any ideas why this method isn't working? Error is "Cannot resolve method 'If(boolean)'

Comment: did you implement onCheckedChangeListener?

Comment: The error is a typo: he wrote `If` instead of `if`. This question shouldn't even be answered.

Comment: While I disagree that this question 'shouldn't be answered' on the basis of the problem simply being a typo, I Googled the error message and the top hit was the duplicate linked above, with an accepted answer of how to fix this - for _this_ reason it gets my close vote.

Comment: I also disagree that this question shouldn't be answered because it's "just a typo." This question has a clear answer and is useful to beginner programs (clearly, at least two people have had this problem.) In fact, I think people should go back and upvote the question this duplicates.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow, user3001471! Most questions have at least some conversation criticising them, and even the most experienced users occasionally post a question that is closed or downvoted. I'm sorry your question got a frosty reception, and I hope you continue contributing here!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (Yes.isChecked()){
```

not

```
If (Yes.isChecked()){
```

(lower case i )